# I want to display only one product image

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

**This is Code in node js**

```
const result = await OrderDB.aggregate([
      { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'products',
          localField: 'product',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'productDetail',
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
         
          productDetail: {
            name: 1,
            price: 1,
            productImage: 1,
          },
        },
      },
    ])
```

**This is the response of code**

```
{
    "message": "Get Order Successfully",
    "result": [
        {
            "_id": "5ff47348db5f5917f81871aa",
            "productDetail": [
                {
                    "name": "Camera",
                    "productImage": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5fe9b8a26720f728b814e246",
                            "img": "uploads\\product\\7Rq1v-app-7.jpg"
                        },
                        {
                            "_id": "5fe9b8a26720f728b814e247",
                            "img": "uploads\\product\\FRuVb-app-8.jpg"
                        }
                    ],
                    "price": 550
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**I want to display only one *`productImage`*  from the response using nodejs and mongoose**

> This is using in aggregate projection

> I was use *`$arrayElemAt`* but it is don't work

> I also use *`$first`* but it is don't work

> so projection method I use to display only one `*productImage*`

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data looks like multi level nested.

You have `array of results, each result contains array of productDetails`

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hQZIdo6okvo)

You need to unwind the data to get the first `productImage`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$result"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$result.productDetail"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      pImage: {
        "$first": "$result.productDetail.productImage"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

With the above response

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      productDetails: {
        $map: {
          input: "$productDetail",
          in: {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                productImage: {
                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                    "$$this.productImage",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qXAgiJpChIm)**